# What means "that get them"?

Tags: idioms

Here is some speech of Bill Gates.

"State budgets are big, big money -- I'll show you the numbers -- and they get very little scrutiny. The understanding is very low. 
Many of the people involved have special interests or short-term interests 
**that get them** not thinking about what the implications of the trends are. 
And these budgets are the key for our future."

Does anyone help me to understand about "that get them"?

Comment: the sense is...interests that *make them not think about*..

Comment: *that get them not thinking about X = **that cause them not to think about X** = **that make them not think about X***

Comment: Ah, I understood well. So I have one question. Why use "that get them.." instead of "that make them..."? What is little difference between them?

Comment: I'm assuming this wasn't a prepared speech. Something that gets people to think about something is a very common expression. It looks like Gates thought of this first, then realized he needed to negate it. The result is clumsy, but readily understood.

Comment: Anyway, Thanks KarlG and all of them who added good comment.